# Pegar um HttpPostedFileBase e converter para CloudFile (Azure Files) para não precisar escrever no Servidor o Arquivo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-azure

Bom pessoal estou com o seguinte problema.
A controller recebe um HttpPostedFileBase e envio ao Azure e para isso preciso escrever em uma pasta temporária.

Gostaria de saber de uma solução mais elegante onde não precise escrever no disco do Servidor. Resumindo enviar o HttpPostedFileBase direto para o Azure com o CloudFile. Pois esta solução me parece ser mais performática, caso alguma ideia por favor compartilhem.

Segue código abaixo:

```
 CloudStorageAccount _azureFile;

    public UploadArquivo()
    {
        _azureFile = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("azureFile"));
    }
    public void uploadArquivoAzure(HttpPostedFileBase arquivo, string caminhoArquivo)
    {
        //Escreve arquivo no caminho temporario
        arquivo.SaveAs(caminhoArquivo);

        // Criando o cliente do azure para acessar o storage
        CloudFileClient clienteArquivos = _azureFile.CreateCloudFileClient();

        // acessando o serviço de arquivos
        CloudFileShare compartilhamentoArquivos = clienteArquivos.GetShareReference("servicoArquivo");

        if (compartilhamentoArquivos.Exists())
        {
            // cria o diretorio raiz
            CloudFileDirectory dirRaiz = compartilhamentoArquivos.GetRootDirectoryReference();

            // criando o diretorio especifico
            CloudFileDirectory diretorio = dirRaiz.GetDirectoryReference("compartilhamentoArquivos");

            if (diretorio.Exists())
            {
                //Setando o arquivo e caminho do mesmo caminho do arquivo
                CloudFile arquivoEnviado = diretorio.GetFileReference(arquivo.FileName);


                arquivoEnviado.UploadFromFile(arquivo.);

                //arquivoEnviado.DownloadToFile(caminhoArquivo, FileMode.Create);

                //arquivoEnviado.UploadFromFile(caminhoArquivo);

            }
        }
    }
```

Qualquer dica ajudaria bastante.

Answer (score 1):

Para manter seu arquivo em memoria sem precisar gravar no disco, deve-se gravar seu arquivo em um `[System.IO.Stream.MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx)`.

Ficaria algo assim:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("upload")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Upload()
{
    var uploaded = await GravarNaMemoriaAsync(arquivo.InputStream);
    // ...
    EnviarParaNuvem(arquivo.FileName, uploaded);
}

private async Task<Stream> GravarNaMemoriaAsync(Stream stream)
{
        // Verify that this is an HTML Form file upload request
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

    // Create a stream provider for setting up output streams that saves the output under memory
    var streamProvider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();

    // Read the MIME multipart content using the stream provider we just created.
    var bodyparts = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
    var documentStream = await streamProvider.Contents[0].ReadAsStreamAsync();

    var buffer = new byte[documentStream.Length];
    await documentStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    return documentStream;
}
```

Agora, sobre enviar esse aqui para o Azure Storage, acredito que vc não está fazendo da maneira ideal. Voce está usando recursos de sincronização de arquivos em disco com a area de armazenamento em nuvem. Como se tivesse fazendo um "OneDrive" ou "DropBox", e não é bem isso que eu vejo que vc realmente quer fazer.

Se eu entendi bem, você que enviar um arquivo que fizeram upload para sua aplicação e armazena-lo no Azure Storage - e isso está corretíssimo. Porém você deve armazenalo na área de Blobs, dentro de um conteiner do Azure.

Para isso, segue um exemplo de partida:

```
private void EnviarParaNuvem(string meuArquivo, Stream memoryStream)
{
    // Recuperar sua conta de armazenamento via connection string.
    var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
        CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

    // Cria um client blob.
    var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    // Cria uma referencia para um container criado anteriormente.
    var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

    // Cria uma referencia para um blob com nome de "meuArquivo".
    var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(meuArquivo);

    // Cria ou sobrescreve o "meuArquivo" com o conteúdo do seu MemoryStream.
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream);
}
```

Fonte: [Como armazenar arquivos Blob no Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/#carregar-um-blob-em-um-continer).

Comment: Primeiramente muito obrigado pela resposta.
Em seu exemplo no metodo "GravarNaMemoria" em testes o mesmo nao esta retornando conteúdo como stream, vejo que você colocou um vetor de bytes e não o utiliza, em analise ao stream vejo que tem um buffer, porem nao consegui recuperar o mesmo, poderia auxiliar neste caso.

Quanto a utilizar blob eu ainda não percebi direito as grandes diferenças entre blob e file, estou a estudar para melhorar o entendimento e sua colocação ja ajudam bastante.
Inclusive ja encontrei serventia para o File. Obrigado.

Comment: @NapoleãoMenezes, está correto. Alterei o código da resposta com um trecho de código meu antigo. Realmente faltavam alguma coisas.

Comment: @NapoleãoMenezes, quanto à diferença entre usar Blob e File. O File vc usa para sincronizar um arquivo no disco com a nuvem, como se fosse fazer um drive remote. No Blob vc já hospedagem do arquivo em uma área de armazenamento web/HTTP. Veja direitinho, mas eu estou certo que é isso que vc precisa.

Comment: @NapoleãoMenezes a resposta resolveu seu problema?